# fix js spread operator copying over deep values with same key

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, copy, deep-copy

How can I fix below so the `t:false` persists to `b`?

https://jsfiddle.net/5gvxb7wL/

```
const a = { t: true, deep: { t: true} }
const b = { t: false, ...a }
console.log('a', a)
console.log('b', b)
```

consoles

```
"a", {
  deep: {
    t: true
  },
  t: true
}
"b", {
  deep: {
    t: true
  },
  t: true
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Spread `a` *before* listing the `t: false`; the later property listed/interpreted will take priority:

```js
const a = { t: true, deep: { t: true} }
const b = { ...a, t: false }
console.log(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use spread operator **{ t: false, ...a }** like this, is you first change the value of the **t**, and then overwrite it with a copy of all values from object **a** so to use the spread operator correctly you need first spread a copy of an object that you copying, and then you change individual values that you need **{ ...a, t: false }**.